Chern class inequality for (semi-)stable 2 bundles on projective space
In Okonek-Schneider-Spindler they prove (Lemma 1.2.7 on p.168-170) that if a rank 2 bundle $E$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ is stable (resp. semistable), then $c_1(E)^2 - 4c_2(E) < 0$ (resp. $\leq$). However, in the literature it seems that this result holds for $\mathbb{P}^n$ for $n>2$. The proof in [OSS] uses Riemann-Roch in dimension $2$, so I'm not sure how to prove this for $n>2$. If someone could point me to a proof, I'd appreciate it.

This issue is explained in the nice Bourbaki article of Schneider on page 91, I briefly summarize.
Consider the inclusion a hyperplane of dimension $2$, then $i^{*}$ is an isomorphism on $H^{2i}$ $i=1,2$.
Then,by the pull-back property of Chern classes, if $E'= i^{*}E$, $$c_{i}(E') = c_{i}(i^{*}E) = i^{*}c_{i}(E).$$ There when we identify these groups with $\mathbb{Z}$ in the usual way $c_{i}(E') = c_{i}(E)$. Maruyama proved that the restriction of a semi-stable bundle to a very general 2-plane is again semi-stable M. MARUYAMA - Boundedness of semi-stable sheaves of small ranks, Preprint
1978. Barth proved the same result for strict stablity (just for rank 2) with one exception W. BARTH - Some properties of stable rank -2 vector bundles on Pn , Math.
Ann., 226 (1977), 125-15. It turns out that the exception in Barth's result satisfies the Chern number inequality and the result follows.
